# GetJSON method gives same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {
        var user_Data = "";
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            user_Data += '<p class="user">' + value.name + '</p>';
            console.log(data[key].name);
        });
        $("#usernames").append(user_Data);
    });
    
    
    $(document).on('mouseover', '.user', function () {
        $.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {
            var hover_Data = "";
            var user = $(".user");
            for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    if ($(user[i]).text() == data[key].name) {
                        hover_Data = '<p class="hover_user">' + value.name + '</p>';
                    }
                });
                
            }
            
            
            $("#hover_details").append(hover_Data);
        });
    });
});
```

When a user hovers over one of names, I would like to display the same name on hover, however no matter what name I hover over, I get the same name, is there something wrong with my if statement?

Comment: So, by this logic, when you hover over **any** user, you want to display the names for **all** the users?

Comment: Whenever I hover over a specific name, i want only that specific name to append to "#hover_details".

Comment: Then why are you selecting all the users, and looping over them?

Comment: You do appreciate that `getJSON` is async and will not block/return immediately right?

Comment: Also why make a new request each time when it seems you are loading all users? Sounds like all you need is copy some user element that already exists

Comment: Im new to JSON so wasnt sure what I had to call to be specific, thanks guys

Comment: So build all your users with the first ajax request. Then work with the existing elements for page interaction

Answer (score 0):

```js
                                             //pass in the event
$(document).on('mouseover', '.user', function(e) {
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
    var user = $(e.target); //use the user that was hovered
                            //don't find all of them
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if (user.text() == data[key].name) {
          $("#hover_details").append('<p class="hover_user">' + value.name + '</p>');
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the ajax call....just get text of the current user element

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.user', function () {
    var $p = $('<p class="hover_user">').text( $(this).text() );
    $("#hover_details").append($p);      
});
```